# angular : wildcard route loaded instead of route in eagerly loaded modules

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an app with 2 feature modules: 1 is lazy loaded and 1 is eagerly loaded.

In my app routing, I want to add a "**" wildcard route for the "page not found" scenario.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./landing-page/landing-page.module').then(m => m.LandingPageModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

This was working fine with the lazy loaded module.

Now I've added the eagerly loaded module with it's own routing module. So my "app routing" above remains the same. I just import the eagerly loaded module in my app module. This is the routing config of my eagerly loaded module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path:"people", 
    children: [
      { path: "invite", component: InviteComponent}
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PeopleRoutingModule { }
```

My problem is

- When I keep the wildcard route in my app routing, the people/invite route is never reached.
- When I remove the wildcard route, people/invite can be reached.

**So how can I add a "page not found" scenario?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution which is much better than my previous one...

In app.module, make sure you put the routing module behind the eagerly loaded module!

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    PeopleModule, /* Eagerly loaded module with routing*/
    UsersModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule /* Make sure the app routing module is imported after the eagerly loaded module!! */
 ]
```

Comment: In my case Routing Module (AppRoutingModule in my case) was put behind/after the Eagerly Loaded Module (AuthModule in my case), still, it was not working.

However, I put AuthModule in the first position of imports, and Routing Module in the last, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution, but I doubt this is the best possible solution...

When I add a wildcard route which redirects to the root route in my eagerly loaded feature module, then everything seems to work...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path:"people", 
    children: [
      { path: "invite", component: InviteComponent}
    ]
  },
  { path:"**", redirectTo: '/', pathMatch:"full"}
];
```

The problem with this solution is that I need to add a wildcard route in every module... Doesn't seem like the best solution...